# ExcelJS cross sheet formula parsing error

Tags: node.js, typescript, exceljs

I have a title sheet, where I am trying to sum up all the values in Cell E6 for all my other sheets.

Off of [this](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/315) GitHub issue, I have tried this:

```
spreadsheetExport.worksheets.map((worksheet: Worksheet, index: number) => {
        if (index !== 1) {
            formulaArr.push(`${worksheet.name}!E6`);
        }
    });
    const formula = formulaArr.join(' + ');
    titleSheet.getCell('B3').value = { formula, date1904: false };
```

these have all led to an error (photo attached) in the export which reads:
`The formula couldn’t be imported and was replaced by the last calculated value.`

If I try to do it manually, I can get this formula [image], but if I copy that same notation, I  get the same error `The formula couldn’t be imported and was replaced by the last calculated value. Original formula: ='Master Bedroom'::Table 1::E6 + 'Dining Room'::Table 1::E6 + 'Bedroom #1'::Table 1::E6` and if I copy the erroring formula and paste it into the cell it works.

Please help, I have been stuck for days, with no end in sight. I have tried named cells as well but that is not working either.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just missing quotes!

Solution:

```
if (index > 0) {
    formulaArr.push(`'${worksheet.name}'!E6`);
}
```